# Why is sepsis more common with leukemia than with cancers involving physical tumors?

Tags: cancer, infection, treatment, bacteria, tumors

Does it have something to do with differences between leukemia versus other cancers, or differences between the treatments of leukemia versus other cancers?

Quote from [the source](https://www.cancer.ca/en/cancer-information/diagnosis-and-treatment/managing-side-effects/septic-shock/?region=on):

> People with cancers of the blood, such as leukemia, are more likely to develop septic shock than those with solid tumours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a combination.

By definition, leukemia affects the production and/or development of white blood cells ([MedlinePlus - Leukemia](https://medlineplus.gov/leukemia.html)). If not enough white blood cells are produced (AKA neutropenia) or those white blood cells don't work properly, the body is less able to fight infection, potentially leading to sepsis ([MedlinePlus - Low WBC](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/patientinstructions/000675.htm)). A solid tumor won't usually affect white blood cell production like this.

Also, leukemia is pretty much always treated with chemotherapy ([Mayo Clinic - Leukemia](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/leukemia/diagnosis-treatment/drc-20374378)), which causes neutropenia. Chemo is common in treating solid tumors, but not universal; some early breast cancers, for example, are treated only with surgery, or only surgery and radiation ([NCCN Patient Guidelines DCIS - see pg. 29](https://www.nccn.org/patients/guidelines/content/PDF/stage_0_breast-patient.pdf)).

Additionally, radiation for leukemia can weaken the immune system. Radiation for solid tumors is usually very targeted to minimize side effects, but for leukemia a larger area often needs to be treated. This makes many side effects, including neutropenia, more common for that type of radiation ([Mayo Clinic - Low Blood Cell Counts](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/cancer/in-depth/cancer-treatment/ART-20046192?p=1)).

Lastly, "Full body radiation", which completely destroys the body's ability to produce any white blood cells, may be done in preparation for a bone marrow transplant to treat leukemia. Severe infections, including sepsis, are a serious potential side effect ([MedlinePlus - Bone Marrow Transplant](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003009.htm)).